# Citing antichronistic works -- worth commenting that the publication order is counter intuitive?

Tags: citations

In my related works section of the paper I am writing,
there are two papers by roughly the same group of authors.
Paper A (2015), and Paper B (2014).

Paper B (2014) is based on Paper A (2015), and cites it as a unpublished work.
But for some reason or another Paper B was published first.
(Possibly because Paper A was a more significant work, so was targetted at a better venue with a longer review time, whereas paper B was a relatively minor extension published as a relatively unknown workshop.)

I'm only briefly discussing them in my related literature section.
Do I need to call attention to the fact that Paper B is based on Paper A, even though the dates don't line up.

I currently have something like:

> Paper A (2015) prepared the dataset using methods Foo.
>   This dataset was uses in the evaluation of the models of Paper A (2015) and Paper B (2014) which were based on the principle of Bar.
>   Paper B (2014) extends Paper A (2015) by adding support for Buzz.

Comment: Do you need a relation of A and B? I.e. do you need to say that B uses results from A, or could you just go and say "this was studied in A and B"?

Comment: I quiet possibly could say: _"Paper A (2015) prepared the dataset using methods Foo. Paper A (2015) and Paper B (2014) are based on the principle of Bar."_ though it would limit my capacity to discuss them in much detail at all. (Which might be Ok, since I wasn't intending on doing too much detail.)

Comment: Another possibility would be to take them together: Researchgroup X showed in A,B, that ...

Comment: How significant is your paper?  The more significant your paper, the more likely it is to be read far into the future, when researchers might use it as an overview of the history of the ideas involved.

Answer (score 5):

The relation between paper A and B seems like an unnecessary detail. As you imply they are both about the same project. Keep it concise.

White et al used Bar and Buzz in [A,B] to analyze a dataset using methods Foo.

[Then go on to say why this is important and relates to your own research]